# Correct usage of localStorage.clear()

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I understand that localStorage.clear() clears all key/value pairs created by for localStorage.  From what I read, that means all localStorage information for a particular domain.  I also understand that there may be different localStorage(s) keys for different browsers.

The part that I am unclear about (no pun intended) is:

1. Does it clear all key/value pairs created on a PC that were created by any program that sets a localStorage anywhere on the same browser?

or

2. Does it clear all key/value pairs created on the PC for the program currently executing by the browser?

In other words, does the localStorage.clear() function clear ALL settings for a PC, even the ones the programmer might not know are in existence?  It is deleting localStorage values for settings of other programs executed on the PC?  If so, what is the protections to avoid clearing values not intended to be modified by your particular program for OTHER programs using localStorage?

I found a function to create a list of all localStorage values on the PC.

```
    const allKeys = Object.keys(localStorage);
    
    console.log(allKeys.join('\n'));
```

So, do I need to check this list for ONLY the keys that I use in my localStorage usage and then remove setting with localStorage.remove(key) only, or is this an unnecessary step?

**ADDENDUM to question:**
Consider original domain is 'myDomain.org' or something similar.
If I have two programs that use some localStorage settings,
say 'script1' uses 'contacts'
and 'script2' uses 'xmasList'

I can remove localStorage in each INDIVIDUAL script with localStorage.removeItem('contacts') or
localStorage.removeItem('xmasList');

If I use localStorage.clear() in EITHER of the scripts, does it remove the all storage key/values for BOTH since I am in the same domain?
If yes, it would seem to be dangerous to use without some prior thought!

**Page Examples of Questions about localStorage**

Save following as 'lsPage1.html'

```
    <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes"/>
    <title> Share Page1 Information with localStorage </title>
    
    <!-- link rel="stylesheet" href="common.css" media="screen" -->
    <!-- Highly modified from: https://medium.com/@cyberbotmachines/how-to-pass-value-from-one-html-page-to-another-using-javascript-3c9ab62df4d -->
    </head><body>
    <h1> Page 1 localStorage Demo </h1>
    <h3> <a href='https://medium.com/@cyberbotmachines/how-to-pass-value-from-one-html-page-to-another-using-javascript-3c9ab62df4d'
            target='_blank'> Reference </a>
    </h3>
    <pre  id="demo"></pre>
    
    <input type="text" id='lsInfo' value=''>
    <button onclick="saveInfo(document.getElementById('lsInfo').value)">Save Page 1 Info</button> 
    <button onclick="showAllLS()"> Show Keys </button>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <button onclick="demo.innerHTML=localStorage.getItem('lsPage1')"> Page 1 Info </button>
    <button onclick="demo.innerHTML=localStorage.getItem('lsPage2')"> Page 2 Info </button>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <button onclick="localStorage.removeItem('lsPage1')"> localStorage.removeItem('lsPage1') </button>
    <button onclick="confirmClearAll()"> localStorage.clear() </button>
    
    <script>
     const demo = document.getElementById('demo');
    
     function saveInfo(info) {
       localStorage.setItem('lsPage1', info);
       console.log(info);
     }
    
     function showAllLS() {
        const allKeys = Object.keys(localStorage);
        demo.innerHTML = allKeys.join('\n');
        demo.innerHTML += '\nlsPage1Info: '+localStorage.getItem('lsPage1')
     }
     
     function confirmClearAll() {
       var txt;
       var r = confirm("Really clear ALL?");
       if (r == true) {
         txt = "You pressed OK!";
         localStorage.clear();
       } else {
         txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
       }
       demo.innerHTML = txt;
    }
    </script>
    
    </body></html>
```

And save following as 'lsPage2.html'

```
    <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes"/>
    <title> Share Page2 Information with localStorage </title>
    
    <!-- link rel="stylesheet" href="common.css" media="screen" -->
    <!-- Highly modified from: https://medium.com/@cyberbotmachines/how-to-pass-value-from-one-html-page-to-another-using-javascript-3c9ab62df4d -->
    </head><body>
    <h1> Page 2 localStorage Demo </h1>
    <h3> <a href='https://medium.com/@cyberbotmachines/how-to-pass-value-from-one-html-page-to-another-using-javascript-3c9ab62df4d'
            target='_blank'> Reference </a>
    </h3>
    <pre  id="demo"></pre>
    
    <input type="text" id='lsInfo' value=''>
    <button onclick="saveInfo(document.getElementById('lsInfo').value)">Save Page 2 Info</button>
    <button onclick="showAllLS()"> Show Keys </button>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <button onclick="demo.innerHTML=localStorage.getItem('lsPage1')"> Page 1 Info </button>
    <button onclick="demo.innerHTML=localStorage.getItem('lsPage2')"> Page 2 Info </button>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <button onclick="localStorage.removeItem('lsPage2')"> localStorage.removeItem('lsPage2') </button>
    <button onclick="confirmClearAll()"> localStorage.clear() </button>
    
    <script>
     const demo = document.getElementById('demo');
     
     function saveInfo(info) {
       localStorage.setItem('lsPage2', info);
       console.log(info);
     }
    
     function showAllLS() {
        const allKeys = Object.keys(localStorage);
        demo.innerHTML = allKeys.join('\n');
        demo.innerHTML += '\nlsPage2Info: '+localStorage.getItem('lsPage2')
     }
    
     function confirmClearAll() {
       var txt;
       var r = confirm("Really clear ALL?");
       if (r == true) {
         txt = "You pressed OK!";
         localStorage.clear();
       } else {
         txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
       }
       demo.innerHTML = txt;
    }
    </script>
    
    </body></html>
```

Both pages are stored as separate files in the same directory.

Now when executed by browsers:

1. You can save some information about the page
   or
2. You can retrieve the information saved

Then you can retrieve saved information for each page

EXCEPT:
lsPage1.html DOES NOT retrieve lsPage2.html information.
and visa versa.
I cannot figure out why, when I thought it was supposed to while in the same domain.

Also, you can remove the information for a particular page.  This works OK.

But when you ask for all the localStorage keys, you only get the one for the page you are in.

Again, I cannot figure out why, when I thought it was supposed to while in the same domain.

I must be thinking or doing something wrong (all pages validate) in my concept of localStorage usage.

I hope I have explained my quandry.

Comment: You said it in your question: it's for the relevant domain for the code that calls `.clear()`. It's particular to a single browser, so if you have Firefox and Chrome and Edge installed, it only clears the storage for the **one** browser where the call is made.

Comment: In general web code is firewalled from the "PC".

Comment: What do you mean by "*program currently executing by the browser*"? A browser displays web pages, it doesn't execute "programs". So it's also unclear what you mean by "*I have two programs that use some localStorage settings*".

Comment: "*it would seem to be dangerous to use without some prior thought!*" - programming is like that, yes.

Comment: To avoid being asked to not have an "extended discussion in comments" on this site,  I would invite you to further discussions on the chat site of this thread.  (See message below).  Link: [link](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239762/discussion-between-jmrker-and-pointy) https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239762/discussion-between-jmrker-and-pointy

Comment: @Bergi: I mean the actions of the browser of the current focus of a browser tab.  Pages if that make more sense.  I could have two pages open with different local storage requirements for both.  I'm trying to determine the effect of each page on the other if one or both does a localStorage.clear().

Comment: @jmrker Yes, it will - web storage is designed to be shared between all pages on the same origin (domain), even if on different paths. The browser doesn't know you host two separate web applications on subpages.

Comment: @Bergi: See program examples added to the original post for demonstration of my questions.

Comment: What do you mean by "*Save following as 'lsPage1.html'*"? The important thing is how you are loading them in the browser. What web server are you using? Notice that when opening local files using the `file://` protocol, there are no domains and the same-origin rule behaves differently.

Comment: Per site request, going to chat room for further discussions.

Each example is slightly different key for local storage.  Open files in browser for local storage actions.

Am using the FF browser.  When tested with Chrome browser, each demo stores and retrieve slightly different.  In FF, only current LS items are show, while in Chrome, both are save and shown.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239784/discussion-between-jmrker-and-bergi).

Answer (score 1):

You can only access local storage values from the domain the javascript is called from. You cannot view local storage from other domains using javascript on your own page.

There is a "firewall" between local storage and your pc. Though some browsers allow you to view local storage for all domains.

Executing `localStorage.clear()` will only clear local storage for the domain at which the script is executed.

ie. If you execute it on `www.stackoverflow.com` it will clear all local storage for the stackoverflow domain. Leaving all local storage you may have on your system/browser that reside outside of stackoverflow.

Comment: Does not answer the question.  It only restates the original statements of the question.

Comment: @jmrker well the first part of your question is basically the answer to the rest of your question. Browsers keep separate domains isolated; that's fundamental web security. And one browser can't affect the local storage values for *any* domain kept by another browser.

Comment: @Pointy I don't seem to be getting my question across.  See addendum in original question for a second attempt of question clarification.

Comment: @jmrker "script1" and "script2" are not "two different programs".  All scripts loaded into a page are part of the same page environment.

Comment: @Pointy: 'script1' and 'script2' are in different program files.  Each program is using a different script, just in the same domain.

Comment: Quick question: Are /paths/ included as part of the domain?  As in: www.domain.com/path/subpath/program.html

Comment: No, paths don't count. Scripts in different files are effectively **combined** when they get to the web page; they share the same global namespace. Code in one file can freely access symbols (public symbols) in other files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239762/discussion-between-jmrker-and-pointy).